# Native Android browser not showing div at jquery.mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, browser

On the `Chrome browser`, I get everything working, but, if I want to make it work at the native `Android Browser`, I can't see the div I want to show. Instead, it shows me the first span with the class leftscroller.

How could this be? I tried **Android 4.1.2 and 4.1.3 browsers**.

This is the JS code:

```
    $('.navigation-block').on('click', function(){
        $(this).parents('#navigation.small').toggleClass('open');
    });

    /* Scrollable */
    var showScrollIndicators = function() {
        var subnav = $('#navigation.small .subnav')
        if (subnav.length > 0) {
            var scrollLeft = subnav.scrollLeft();
            var viewportWidth = subnav.innerWidth();
            var scrollWidth = subnav[0].scrollWidth;
            var leftScroller = $('#navigation.small').find('.leftscroller'),
                rightScroller = $('#navigation.small').find('.rightscroller');
            leftScroller.addClass('enabled');
            rightScroller.addClass('enabled');
            if (scrollLeft === 0) {
                // we've reached the far left part of the scroll area
                leftScroller.removeClass('enabled');
            }
            if (scrollWidth - scrollLeft <= viewportWidth) {
                // we've reached the far right part
                rightScroller.removeClass('enabled');
            }
        }
    };

    /* Add scroll indicators */
    $('#navigation.small .ph_subnav').append(
        '<span class="leftscroller">You can scroll to the left</span>' +
        '<span class="rightscroller">You can scroll to the right</span>'
    );
    showScrollIndicators();

    $('#navigation.small .subnav').scroll(function() {
        showScrollIndicators();
    });
```

What am I doing wrong? So the whole area which falls beneath /*Scrollable*/ is not shown.

Comment: once check your browser is in mobile mode (or) desktop mode.. If there is No option use Dolphin Browser for android i usually ckeck with this browser.. It has desktop mode enabled in andi android version 2.3 to 4.3.. So ti will helpful..

Comment: That is an alternative browser to use, but not a solution my brother.